# How to create an installer for Excel Add-in?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have created Excel Add-in in Javascript (Node.js), I used Yeoman generator. My add-in adds custom formulas to Excel. How can I create installer for this? I don't want to publish it in Office Store, I want to publish it on GitHub on or my website.

I thought about Office Product Addin wizard, but it's available only in Visual Studio, I'm using VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make an installer for Office Add-ins because there's no way to get access to the internal Office code that hosts and reads the manifest. The supported ways of installing add-ins are described at [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish). You should probably use Centralized Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Office web add-ins can't be distributed using installers. They must deployed or sideloaded somehow.

You can publish your manifest so users could sideload the add-in. Or administrators could deploy the add-in centralized, see [Manage add-ins in the Microsoft 365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-addins-in-the-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide).

The best what you could do is to publish your add-in to the AppSource (store), see [Make your solutions available in Microsoft AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center) for more information. They are designed to be distributed that way.

The [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) page describes all possible options.

Answer (score 0):

I distribute my Add-in via installer, its just a bunch of regedits wrapped in an executable.

You'll be basically automating the sideloaing process.

There is no official method, but it surely can be done.